Rook-ceph. Blok Storage. FailedAttachVolume. Pod of sample is not started
I installed ceph cluster in kuber according to the instructions https://rook.io/docs/rook/v1.12/Getting-Started/intro/
on 3 nodes
wn-1 - /dev/sdb 200 GB HDD 
wn-2 - /dev/sdb 200 GB SSD 
wn-3 - /dev/sdb 200 GB SSD
ceph -s shows HEALTH_OK 

Then I created RBD Storage Class rook-ceph-block. https://rook.io/docs/rook/v1.9/Storage-Configuration/Block-Storage-RBD/block-storage/#provision-storage and tried to launch wordpress sample
$ kubectl create -f wordpress.yaml
service/wordpress created
persistentvolumeclaim/wp-pv-claim created
deployment.apps/wordpress created
$ k svc wordpress
NAME        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
wordpress   LoadBalancer   10.233.14.123   <pending>     80:32669/TCP   15h
$ k get pods
NAME                                           READY   STATUS              RESTARTS      AGE
wordpress-658d46dddd-qbzft                     0/1     ContainerCreating   0             45s
Pod is not started because "AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-cf4908c8-5a6d-4a41-aadc-ec3cdd49ed79" : timed out waiting for external-attacher of rook-ceph.rbd.csi.ceph.com CSI driver to attach volume"
$ k describe pods wordpress-658d46dddd-qbzft
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age    From                     Message
  ----     ------              ----   ----                     -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling    2m31s  default-scheduler        0/7 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/7 nodes are available: 7 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
  Normal   Scheduled           2m29s  default-scheduler        Successfully assigned mongodb/wordpress-658d46dddd-qbzft to k8s-worker2
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume  30s    attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-cf4908c8-5a6d-4a41-aadc-ec3cdd49ed79" : timed out waiting for external-attacher of rook-ceph.rbd.csi.ceph.com CSI driver to attach volume 0001-0009-rook-ceph-0000000000000002-5ec1f05b-fdb1-4786-924c-953ee825ee2d

$ kubectl get volumeattachment
    NAME                                                                   ATTACHER                     PV
              NODE          ATTACHED   AGE
    csi-0909c664ed3633fd66dce1746c0fbf2fd2967c9802df7a39a1fa123f9a4ac10a   rook-ceph.rbd.csi.ceph.com   pvc-cf4908c8-5a6d-4a41-aadc-ec3cdd49ed79   k8s-worker2   false      94m

I've looked all over the internet and haven't found anything. Maybe because I mix of HDD and SSD

What is the status of the ceph cluster?

Status of ceph cluster - HEALTH_OK

Please update your question instead of pasting output into the comments.
It looks like a permission issue to me.

$ k logs csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-5f69d6ffbc-jgcw2 -c csi-attacher
... Error saving VolumeAttachment User "system:serviceaccount:rook-ceph:rook-csi-rbd-provisioner-sa" cannot patch resource "volumeattachments/status" in API group "storage.k8s.io" at the cluster scope


I reinstall ceph cluster using SSD disk only and everything worked.
In general, do not mix SSD and HDD disk)
